# how do i get my rss feed image to show in feedburner?

Tags: rss, feed

How do I put image in rss feed to show up in feedburner newsletter..

```
<item>
 <title><![CDATA[TEST ONE TITLE]]></title>
 <link>www.example.com/test/title</link>
 <source url="http://www.youtube.com/aaaaa"><![CDATA[TEST ONE TITLE]]></source>

 <description>&lt;img src="http://www.example.com/img1.jpg" style="border: medium none ; display: block;" /&gt;TEST ONE DESCRIPTION.</description>

 <content:encoded><![CDATA[<img src="http://www.example.com/img1.jpg" /> TEST ONE DESCRIPTION ]]></content:encoded>
 <pubDate>Sun, 28 Oct 2010</pubDate>
 <author>USER</author>
 <category>CategoryOne</category>
 <guid>http://www.example.com</guid>

</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<item>
    <!-- ... -->
    <enclosure url="http://www.example.com/img1.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="[SIZE_IN_BYTES]" />
    <!-- ... -->
</item>
```